# Redirection Loop in CakePHP Application

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using CakePHP v1.2 for my web application hosted here: http://lol-land.in

The application was working fine till Yesterday, but it suddenly started to get stuck in some redirection loops. What makes it weirder is the fact that the problem is with just one controller: posts. And even in that most of the functions are working. But http://lol-land.in/posts is redirecting to lol-land.in/posts/view/133 which is in turn redirecting to itself.

Actually 110 of the 117 posts of the form /posts/view/ are stuck in this 302 redirection.

Can anyone please tell me what could have caused this?

[CakePHP 1.3 and PHP5]

Edit: Adding View Logic

```
function view($id = null) {
$this->log("View Logic Entry", LOG_DEBUG);
// These Log entires are missing 

$this->layout = 'postview';
if (!$id) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Post.', true));
    $this->log("Redirect due to missing id", LOG_DEBUG);
    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
}
$log = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
$logid = $log['id'];

$temp = $this->Post->read(null, $id);

$ratings = $temp['Rating'];

$this->set(compact('up', 'down', 'userrated', 'userrateid'));

$coms = $temp['Comment'];
$comuser = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($coms); $i++) {
    $comuser[$i] = $coms[$i]['user_id'];
}
$comuser = $this->Post->User->find('list', array( 'fields'=>array('User.id', 'User.username'),
                      'conditions'=>array("User.id" => $comuser)
                      ));
$this->set(compact('comuser'));

$this->pageTitle = $temp['Post']['title'];
$this->set('post', $temp);
$alltypes = $this->Post->Type->find('list', array('fields'=> array('Type.id', 'Type.typename')));
$selectedtab = -1;
$this->set(compact('alltypes', 'selectedtab' ));


//Calling updateFBStats
// Removed because unnecessary.
```

}

Comment: Update: It stopped working for ALL the posts. :(

Comment: You call `$this->set` too many times. Do it once. Post you Auth component settings from `beforeFilter()`. I do not have any problem with accessing http://lol-land.in/posts/view/133.

Comment: But your site is really slow. 5-6 sec for each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you are either 1) using circular references with the Auth component OR 2) the function in your controller is redirecting do to something within the method. Can you show the code of posts_controller.php function view() ?

Comment: The 'view' action was calling some 3-4 other actions, and somewhere I had used == to compare values and not ===. So null == 0 gave 'true' which resulted in redirection back to view. And hence the issue.

Basically, very bad programming on my side.
But, Thanks for the help :)